# Subset of Well-ordered set A is Order-Isomorphic to A or section of A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Claim**

Let A is well-ordered set.

$C \approxeq A$ or $C \approxeq section \;of \;A$ $\forall C$ s.t. $C \subset A$

How to prove above claim?

Comment: I presume you are asking to prove that $C$ is order-isomorphic to an initial segment of $A$. The key to this is transfinite recursion.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303822/verification-c-approxeq-a-or-c-approxeq-textsection-of-a-forall-c?