# (Verification) $C \approxeq A$ or $C \approxeq \text{section of } A$ $\forall C$ s.t. $C \subset A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Claim**

Let A is well-ordered set.

$C \approxeq A$ or $C \approxeq \text{section of } A$ $\forall C$ s.t. $C \subset A$

**Proof**

If $C=A$, $C \approxeq A$ since a well-ordered set is order-isomorphic to oneself.

If $C \neq A$, there $\exists a \in A$ s.t. $a \notin C$. Then

$A\setminus C = \{a \in A \;|\;a \notin C\}$.

Now, since A is well-ordered, there $\exists$ least element in $A\setminus C$, so let this least element be $m_0$.

Now let $S_{m_o} = \{a \in A \;|\; a< m_0\}$ which is a section of A.

Now define $\phi : C \to S_{m_0}$ s.t. $\forall C_0, C_1 \in C$ if $C_0 \le C_1$ then $\phi(C_0) \le \phi(C_1)$

There $\exists \;\text{such}\;\phi$ since $C$ and  $S_{m_0}$ are all-well-ordered since A is well-ordered.

So by definition $\phi$ is increasing. Also, $\phi$is bijective since the number of element in $C$ and $S_{m_0}$ is equal.

Thus,  $\phi^{-1}$ also exists and it is also increasing and bijective by definition.

Thus $C \approxeq \text{section of } A$

Comment: If $m_0$ is the least element of $A$ (which will be the case if the least element of $A$ is not an element of $C$) then $S_{m_0}=\varnothing$. If moreover $C\neq\varnothing$ then no function $\phi:C\to S_{m_0}$ exists.

Comment: There are a few mistakes and unjustified statements here. "$\phi$ is bijective" for instance isn't true : a constant $\phi$ would satisfy your conditions but obviously wouldn't be bijective. And if you require that $\phi$ be strictly increasing, then you need more justification, and it will not be true in general for your choice of $m_0$.

Comment: Hint: define (recursively) $\phi:C\to A$ as the function that sends $c\in C$ to the least element of $A\setminus\{\phi(x)\mid x\in C\wedge x<c\}$.