# (Verification) well-definiteness of order between ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ be well-ordered set.
Denote $ord(A) = \alpha$ and $ord(B) = \beta$ when $A \approxeq \alpha $ and $B \approxeq \beta$.

Then we define:

$\alpha \lt \beta$ if $A \approxeq \text{section of } B$

$\alpha = \beta$ if $A \approxeq  B$

$\alpha \gt \beta$ if $B \approxeq \text{section of } A$

Claim: above definition is well-defined.

**proof**

take $A', B'$ which are well-ordered sets s.t. $ord(A') = \alpha$ and $ord(B') = \beta$. Then $A' \approxeq \alpha$ and $B' \approxeq \beta$ by definition of ordinal.

If $A \approxeq \alpha$ and $A' \approxeq \alpha$, $A \approxeq A'$, thus, $ord(A) = ord(A')$. Similarly, $ord(B) = ord(B')$

Now, if $A' \approxeq \text{section of }B'$, $A\approxeq \text{section of }B$ holds since $A\approxeq A'$ and $B \approxeq B'$.

Thus, from $A\approxeq \text{section of }B$, $\alpha \lt \beta$ when $A' \approxeq \text{section of }B'$.

Similarly $\alpha = \beta$ and $\alpha \gt \beta$ holds when $A\approxeq B'$ and $B' \approxeq \text{section of }A'$ respectively.

Comment: That's a weird definition of the order on the ordinals but your proofs works. If you wanted more details you could mention the transitivity of isomorphism, and the fact that the image of a section under an isolorphism is still a section

Comment: @Max isn't that two facts are too much trivial? I know what I mean by "trivial" is mathematically ambiguous however. Any nice recommendation to show two facts with your mathematical expression?

Comment: Yes, they are easy, but since you didn't seem sure about your proof, I gave you a way to detail it a bit more to see that it is correct

Comment: @Max got it. You're right. Will attach what you pointed out.

Comment: @Max https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303822/verification-c-approxeq-a-or-c-approxeq-textsection-of-a-forall-c

could you help to verify this too? this is much more rough and looks incorrect